# How do I bind a DataGrid Width to a converter?

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I want to include the size of the VerticalScrollbar when i define the width of a DataGrid.
So far i wrote a Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))] 
public class VerticalScrollbarConverter : IValueConverter   
{
    #region IValueConverter Member
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {   
        if (value is double)
            return (double)value + SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I included my converter in the xaml namespace with:

```
xmlns:Core="clr-namespace:Core;assembly=SMS_Core"
```

And I defined the converter as a (window) resource:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Core:VerticalScrollbarConverter x:Key="VerticalScrollbarConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Since all of my DataGrid.Columns have a fixed Value I know the value that i need to pass.
How do I tell my GridView Width property in xaml to use the converter?

I know that my question is pretty basic. As you can tell I am very new to WPF.

Thanks in advance for every hint. If you need some more info or context just ask away.

Comment: You can just use the StaticResource keyword in the Binding, e.g: `Width="{Binding TheWidth, Converter={StaticResource VerticalScrollbarConverter}}"`

Comment: No problems, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from sa_ddam213 didn't exactly solve the problem. But it sure did push me into the right direction.
To pass the value automatically I had to do the following:
I created a property in the window class called TotalColumnWidth. Returning this:

```
myDataGrid.Columns.Sum(c => c.ActualWidth);
```

The xaml is the following:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=TotalColumnWidth,  Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=VerticalScrollbarConverter}}"
```

Using the converter mentioned above.

Comment: _Root is the name of the Window.